# Got AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'created_at' while running my program . please help me

Tags: pandas

I am collecting tweets from twitter in a json format, I converted it to csv format. I am reading the csv file using pandas for pre processing it gives me an error. The code I tried is given below

```
    df=pd.read_csv("12.csv",delim_whitespace=True)
    print (df)
    #df.Timestamp = pd.to_datetime(df.created_at) 
    user_data = [[tweet.created_at,tweet.id,p.clean(tweet.full_text),tweet.lang] for tweet in 
    df.iterrows(index=True, name='Pandas')]             
    
    tweet_df = pd.DataFrame(data=user_data,columns=["created_at",'id','Text','lang'])
    print("no of records:",len(tweet_df))
                    
    tweet_df.to_csv('E:/vcn/clean/123.csv')
```

I am getting the following error, I tried alternatives suggested , but results are same. please help me

```
runfile('E:/vcn/8covaxin.py', wdir='E:/vcn')
      
0      {"created_at": "Thu Apr 08 06:46:30 +0000 2021...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
1      {"created_at": "Thu Apr 08 06:46:07 +0000 2021...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
24880  {"created_at": "Wed Mar 31 08:20:32 +0000 2021...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   

[24881 rows x 1 columns]
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "E:\vcn\8covaxin.py", line 53, in <module>
    df.Timestamp = pd.to_datetime(df.created_at)

  File "C:\Users\balaj\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 5274, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'created_at'
```

Answer (score 0):

You tweet dataframe might not contain `tweet.created_at` columns which you are trying to use here.

```
user_data = [[tweet.created_at
```

You can find the details about the error here.

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'created_at'
```

Comment: "created_at" was in my file. even the same is showing it in the error also while am printing '''print(df)'''. It is printing  in [0] tuple, u can find it in the error

Comment: Can you please share sample of you dataframe in your question.

Comment: <iframe src="https://docs.google.com/document/d/e/2PACX-1vSYPfw-CunQ9OEbl6dKPOoZYzIF7cpoggxkAMTV1qrrcXdmzk9sgZ68DCtRvy4dEt2dApwrRPzIXsQ7/pub?embedded=true"></iframe>

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you when using iterrows can not use the colume_name as an attribute name, because it returns a dict  instead of an object,

Try using the below code

```
df=pd.read_csv("12.csv",delim_whitespace=True)
print (df)
#df.Timestamp = pd.to_datetime(df.created_at) 
user_data = [[tweet["created_at"],tweet["id"],p.clean(tweet["full_text"]),tweet["lang"] for tweet in 
df.iterrows(index=True, name='Pandas')]             

tweet_df = pd.DataFrame(data=user_data,columns=["created_at",'id','Text','lang'])
print("no of records:",len(tweet_df))
                
tweet_df.to_csv('E:/vcn/clean/123.csv')
```

=============================================================

Edited: It returns output as list of tuples in format [(index, data)]

```
df=pd.read_csv("12.csv",delim_whitespace=True)
print (df)
#df.Timestamp = pd.to_datetime(df.created_at) 
user_data = [[tweet[1].created_at, tweet[1].id, p.clean(tweet[1].full_text),tweet[1].lang for tweet in 
df.iterrows()]             

tweet_df = pd.DataFrame(data=user_data,columns=["created_at",'id','Text','lang'])
print("no of records:",len(tweet_df))
                
tweet_df.to_csv('E:/vcn/clean/123.csv')
```

Comment: got the following error

File "E:\vcn\8covaxin.py", line 59, in <module>
    user_data = [[tweet["created_at"],tweet["id"],p.clean(tweet["full_text"]),tweet["lang"]] for tweet in df.itertuples(index=True, name='Pandas')] 'code'

  File "E:\vcn\8covaxin.py", line 59, in <listcomp>
    user_data = [[tweet["created_at"],tweet["id"],p.clean(tweet["full_text"]),tweet["lang"]] for tweet in df.itertuples(index=True, name='Pandas')]


TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: You changed the method from ```df.iterrows``` to ```df.itertuples```,  for this you now get a tuple [like ("a", "b") ] in return and to access details use tweet[0]

Comment: when I use df.iterrows it throws an error like this


  File "E:\vcn\8covaxin.py", line 59, in <module>
    user_data = [[tweet["created_at"],tweet["id"],p.clean(tweet["full_text"]),tweet["lang"]] for tweet in df.iterrows(index=True, name='Pandas')]

TypeError: iterrows() got an unexpected keyword argument 'index'

Comment: remove index param for iterrows call, it by default gives indexes and index take argument mention in below link

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html#pandas.DataFrame.iterrows

Comment: it is giving the  error with "name" param, I deleted the name param too and placed  " user_data = [[tweet["created_at"],tweet["id"],p.clean(tweet["full_text"]),tweet["lang"]] for index,tweet in df.iterrows()] .   even now got error as KeyError: 'created_at'

Comment: Sorry, i have mistaken in understanding the code, I have updated my answer